# Is flash storage affected by magnetic fields?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, sd-card

I have several SD cards and USB flash drives that are often laying around my work space.  Do I have to be careful to keep magnets away from them?  (This paranoia is showing my age - I remember needing to make sure magnets never got near my precious 3.5 inch floppies...)

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degaussing#Degaussing_magnetic_data_storage_media

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Screwdrivers With Magnetic Tips Cause Damage To Electronics?](http://superuser.com/questions/323036/can-screwdrivers-with-magnetic-tips-cause-damage-to-electronics)

Comment: @DiogoRocha The thing about that question is that it is extremely broad and the top answer is anecdotal. I do not think they are duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/338641/is-it-possible-to-wipe-ssd-with-strong-magnetic-force

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, unless the magnet is **REALLY** strong (see below quote). There is not enough magnetic material in them.

> "A magnet powerful enough to disturb the electrons in flash would be powerful enough to suck the iron out of your blood cells"

If the above quote is the case you should not be working where you do.

It is also a big myth that normal magnets can ruin harddrives.

> The same goes for hard drives. The only magnets powerful enough to scrub data from a drive platter are laboratory degaussers or those used by government agencies to wipe bits off media.

But those floppies, don't let them near your magnets.

---

Source: [Busting the Biggest PC Myths | PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/116572/busting_the_biggest_pc_myths.html)

Comment: Wouldn't the force exerted on the electrons be proportional to the speed at which you move the thumb drive through the magnetic field?

Comment: @SimonRichter Actually, it's inversely proportional to the speed you pass over it. Source: many years wiping mag media with electro magnet. Also, my electro magnet will erase a HDD no prob. In fact, the handheld electro mag will make a HDD unable to ever work again if you leave it over the drive too long.

Comment: "You should not be working where you do."  Thank you for that...