# Can headphones damage flash memory or other electronics?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, flash, headphones, wii

Well, I am currently out of town and my sister left my Playstation headphones sitting on top of my Wii and three USB flash drives.

Can the magnets in the headphones damage anything? She returned home before me and already removed the headphones but I can't test them until I get home as she had to leave again.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to wipe SSD with strong magnetic force?](http://superuser.com/questions/338641/is-it-possible-to-wipe-ssd-with-strong-magnetic-force), and also related to [What computer components are currently vulnerable to magnets?](http://superuser.com/questions/113430/what-computer-components-are-currently-vulnerable-to-magnets)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.techhive.com/article/116572/article.html). The short answer is - NO.

This could erase data on tape or diskettes though..