# Is it safe to have a USB stick under this situation?

Tags: usb, magnet, memorystick

I found this kind of magnet key ring:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00IEYF6EO/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A2K9Y6914G7CDO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IEYF6EO)

Is it safe to attach one end to an USB stick?

Comment: **Possible duplicate** of [Is it possible to wipe SSD with strong magnetic force?](http://superuser.com/questions/338641/is-it-possible-to-wipe-ssd-with-strong-magnetic-force) or [Could game cartridges or flash-drives be damaged by the magnet in an external hard-drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/113430/what-computer-components-are-currently-vulnerable-to-magnets)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the magnetic field should not affect anything to the USB drive.

Comment: Those magnets are very very strong, many times more than the normal ones.  That is why I am worried about.