# Magnet on back of macbook pro retina

Tags: macbook-pro-retina

I would like to personalize my MBPR... maybe something like: [image]

My problem is that i would like to change it on a daily basis, like the "Frank" does with hes hats (see 30Rock)... so, a stencil is quite not a optimal solution, because i would be able to use it only once but i could print the image on a magnet, like a fridge magnet, and replace it everyday, my question is: is there a part sensible enough to get damaged by a weak magnet like the one i'm describing?

Comment: The MBP case is aluminum, which is non-magnetic; I don't think a fridge magnet will stick like you think it will.

Comment: Aluminum is not magnetic (or at least not enough for magnets to stick to it). http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~wbreslyn/magnets/is-aluminium-magnetic.html, having said that, there's nothing in a laptop that a weak magnet should have any effect on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What computer components are currently vulnerable to magnets?](http://superuser.com/questions/113430/what-computer-components-are-currently-vulnerable-to-magnets)

Answer (score 1):

Fridge magnet would be too weak to damage any part of your laptop. If your MBP surface is not magnetic,  you can stick a small Stainless Steel sticker on your MBP and you are good to go.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DMJ85QW/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B00DMJ85QW&linkCode=as2&tag=thefrufin09-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DMJ85QW)

Answer (score 0):

A company from Vienna offers reusable MacBook stickers. I got some back when the logo would shine through them becuase I saw a life demonstration and they actually seem just like magnets.

They are NOT magnetic but some sort of "glue-free adhesive film" you can change them on a daily basis :)

https://www.tabtag.com