# Networking equipment proximity to magnets

Tags: interference, magnet

I have a small networking rack (4 switches, router, PDU) and a 188W RMS 10" subwoofer (Logitech Z-5500).

How closely may I position these two items before the magnetic field of the speaker interferes with the operation of the networking equipment, or causes permanent damage over time ?

I've read many opinions on forums elsewhere online, but nothing with compelling evidence. 
Even here there are no substantiated distance (inches, feet, whatever) guidelines: [What computer components are currently vulnerable to magnets?](https://superuser.com/questions/113430/what-computer-components-are-currently-vulnerable-to-magnets)

Comment: "Even here there are no substantiated distance" How large is the magnetic field of your particular magnet? Don't know?  Well *neither do we*. On top of that, we don't have your particular magnet to measure. That's why there's no "one answer" to write down. Check if your devices meet your government's interference regulations or not (ie: FCC in the US) and if they do, go look up those regulations and determine if it's safe or not.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is no magnetic storage (hard drives, floppies, etc), you're not likely to cause any permanent damage... Almost all networking gear these days runs entirely off of solid state components and flash/nvram storage.

It is remotely possible that EMI/RFI from the speaker could get into the network gear and cause issues, but most gear is built to tolerate noisy environments (server farms are full of noisy motors). If that happens, just move the speaker (and possibly reboot the network gear) and all should be good again.