# Can a subwoofer's magnet damage laptop's hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage, speakers, magnet

My laptop (one ssd, one hdd) sits on the (turned off) subwoofer. 
**Does the speakers' magnet shorten the lifespan of my storage devices?**

[image: laptop sitting on a speaker]

Cheers,

Dominic

Comment: Yes; It absolutely can

Comment: Not sure about shortening the life span of mechanical HDDs, but it's a sure-fire way to irrevocably destroy data on the HDD.  Depending on the position of the HDD in relation to the woofer's magnet, it could also interfere with the voice coil inside the HDD, which is what controls the heads. _(Its called a voice coil because it's the exact same principle as a speaker's voice coil.)_

Comment: I agree that this practice will damage your data. Do not do this. It is a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you guys.

Comment: There was a study on this years ago and no it will not affect the data, the size of the magnet has to be extremely powerful (electro magnet) and be placed right on the hdd cover to have any effect on data.

Comment: Hell there is a powerful magnet inside the hard drive itself!. https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=hard-drive-destruction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What computer components are currently vulnerable to magnets?](https://superuser.com/questions/113430/what-computer-components-are-currently-vulnerable-to-magnets)